# "over a call" vs "on a call"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I will explain about the project **over** a call

I will explain about the project **on** a call

I have read [here](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/how-use-over) that over can be used as during

So is explain over a call correct?

which is the correct usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in some cases "over" can be used as during, but this is not one of those cases. I would suggest "in a call". That conveys that your explanation will be "in" (that is, part of) the planned call.  And there's nothing wrong with "during the call". The phrasing "on a call" carries the idea of being engaged in a call, but it's used this way:  "wait a minute, I'm on a call" (he is busy talking on the phone).